# Run time permission app level or activity level

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

In the new api version of android (API 23), we now need to request the permission at the run time. I have a very basic doubt if the permission requested are app level or activity. According to [this](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) documentation **you must check whether you have that permission every time you perform an operation that requires that permission**. So does this mean that the permission is granted at app level but its check has been suggested to be done at the activity level? Also, the check for the permission has been suggested to be done as follows:

```
// Assume thisActivity is the current activity
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
```

Here, we clearly see that the check of the permission is done by passing the context of the activity. If the permission given is at app level why do we require the activity context and not the application context?(though there is a chance that the method internally gets the application context from the activity context.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if the permission requested are app level or activity

All permissions in Android are for the entire app.

> So does this mean that the permission is granted at app level but its check has been suggested to be done at the activity level?

The check to see if you have a permission can be done anywhere, via `checkSelfPermission()`. *Requesting* permission from the user has to be done from an activity, via `requestPermissions()`. The resulting permission grant will be for your entire app.

> If the permission given is at app level why do we require the activity context and not the application context?

Any `Context` will work for `ContextCompat` methods.

Comment: Is it advisable to check for all the permissions required by the app when the app starts? The idea is on startup of the app, check for all the permissions required by all the activities at the MainActivity and then proceed forward. I guess this should make sense only when we do not want to configure activities based on the permissions provided. Comments?

Comment: @Swapnil: "Is it advisable to check for all the permissions required by the app when the app starts? " -- only for those permissions that the app *absolutely* needs. Otherwise, wait until the user performs some UI operation that triggers a code path for which you need the permission. For example, if you are only taking a picture when the user taps a take-picture action bar item, do not worry about the permission until the user taps that action bar item. See: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/best-practices.html#dont-overwhelm

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I guess my app need a  lot of permissions that are inevitable. So, I guess I should put a check at the beginning itself. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Is it possible to call `checkSelfPermission()` from the `Application` class, instead of from an `Activity` class? I'd very much prefer to do it that way if it's possible.

Comment: @RenniePet: Yes, you can call `checkSelfPermission()` using any `Context`. You can only *request* a permission from an `Activity`, though.